# Running load function again on image with window.resize?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have design like this :

```
<img class="imgtest" src="img.png" onload="scaleimg(event)" />
```

Now, I want call `scaleimg(event)` function again for image has `.imgtest` class when window is re-sized.

I have tried but it is not working.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
     $("img").one('load', function(){
         scaleimg(event);
     });
    });
```

Help me for fixing it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid using inline javascript - for your question, you can run `scaleimg()` once when the DOM is ready, and then again when the resize event is triggered on window:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // When DOM is ready, go through each <img> with the class '.imgtest'
    $('img.imgtest').each(function() {
        scaleimg(event);
    });

    // Listen to resize event on $(window)
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('img.imgtest').each(function() {
            scaleimg(event);
        });        
    });
});
```

Even better, you can fire the `.resize()` again when DOM is ready by chaining, saving yourself a few lines of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Listen to resize event on $(window)
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('img.imgtest').each(function() {
            scaleimg(event);
        });        
    }).resize();  // Notice the chaining
});
```

Comment: I have tried all of day but it is not success. Please help me with my HTML file here(http://www.mediafire.com/?wngm0gg25m3ps1d). Thanks you so much. I highly appreciate your help. I will vote your answer to the best. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, we do not accept file transfer here. You post the code you have here, or try to replicate it with JSFiddle.

Comment: Thanks Terry. You can check Fiddle here(http://jsfiddle.net/h9DEF/8/). It's code for scaling image. Fiddle does not run there. Scaling is ok but Window.resize did not working.

Comment: Terry. You here? Have you see my code? please send a lite bit time of yours for my issues. thanks

Comment: What're you trying to achieve in your Fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this only

```
$(window).resize(function() {
         scaleimg();
    });
```